# How to allow :hover to sustain while mouse moves through gap?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}

.btnlist {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.btn {
    height: auto;
    padding: 6px;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.btnlist > .btn {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.btnlist > .btn:not(:last-child) {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.btnlist > .btn ~ .btn {
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown:after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-top: 4px solid #111;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}

.dropdownmenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover > .dropdownmenu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdownmenu > .btn:not(:last-child) {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.dropdownmenu > .btn ~ .btn {
    margin-top: -1px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnlist">
    <div class="btn">Button 1</div>
    <div class="btn dropdown">
        Button 2
        <div class="dropdownmenu">
            <div class="btn">Button 4</div>
            <div class="btn">Button 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">Button 3</div>
</div>
```

In `.dropdownmenu` I have the rule `top: 28px;` and I'd like to leave it like that (or equivalent behavior as demonstrated by the snippet). How can I leave that small gap between the actual menu and the button while allowing the `:hover` behavior to sustain if the mouse enters that gap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change margin with padding.

```
.dropdownmenu {
    padding-top: 2px;
}
```

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: default;
}

.btnlist {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: visible;
}

.btn {
    height: auto;
    padding: 6px;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    border: 1px solid #BBB;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.btnlist > .btn {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.btnlist > .btn:not(:last-child) {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.btnlist > .btn ~ .btn {
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown:after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-top: 4px solid #111;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}

.dropdownmenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover > .dropdownmenu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdownmenu > .btn:not(:last-child) {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.dropdownmenu > .btn ~ .btn {
    margin-top: -1px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnlist">
    <div class="btn">Button 1</div>
    <div class="btn dropdown">
        Button 2
        <div class="dropdownmenu">
            <div class="btn">Button 4</div>
            <div class="btn">Button 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">Button 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah perfect, thank you! I had actually just started thinking that right before I opened your question ^^;